# Are we to close as dupe a question the OP had no idea he was asking?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Note 1: **To make what I'm asking most clear**: *Does the new title stay true to the OP's problem, the way she/he saw it?*

Note 2: I do agree, as I have already said in the comments, that there can be multiple readings here of the OP's intentions. Hence, I do see how this question could be ***too broad***. I have in fact voted myself to close it as such.

As many posters asking a question don't know what their problem is (part of why they're asking), aren't duplicates supposed to be marked for posts asking the same question from the OP's perspective, in the hope that other people having the same question in their mind could find it easily and connect the dots, instead of re-writing the title to mean something else and linking it with an older post agreeing with the now edited title?

I already learned there's no official statement regarding the exact definition of a *duplicate*, and I got the feeling this is an on-going debate here, but couldn't find an answer on meta that felt like it applies exactly to this case: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398502/how-is-memory-allocated-for-vectorchar-in-c/) had its title completely re-written, and so was the case with the older question being marked as one that *already has an answer*. To me, it seemed quite clear the OP in the newer question had failed to realize the case in point of the older question, but this had lead her/him through her/his own thought-process, ending up with the OP surmising about in-memory structure of the container at hand. This obviously requires the additional, earlier part of building an answer for -- a part that doesn't show up in, as it has nothing to do with, the answer to the older question.

Original title of the now closed post was: *'How is memory allocated for vector in C++?'*. The entire text of the post: *For every primitive data type memory locations are contiguous, except for char. It prints some garbage value on the screen. I tried adding v.reserve(4), but the output was the same.* A large enough portion of this text now seems a bit baffling, coupled with the new title being: *'Printing addresses of vector's elements shows garbage'*, as it has nothing to do with memory allocations or contingency, etc. But this new title definitely agrees with the now-edited title of the older post: *'Why does streaming a char pointer to cout not print an address?'*

To me it seemed we have an older question asking about how to print address of a `char` and the newer question explicitly asking what's up with the "memory allocations" of a `std::vector`. Other people might be sharing a similar thought process with the OP of the newer question. Hence, after the title re-writing and the dupe closure (for what may seem to them as a completely different question) they could more easily be prevented from finding the right answer -- which potentially would lead them to ask the same question as this one being now closed as a dupe.

Is this the desired cause-and-effect of closing as a duplicate?

Saying that the answer to the newer question is solving ***the exact same problem*** the older question had is doubtful if you take it that a part of the newer OP's ***problem*** was not knowing how `std::vector` is structured in memory, or at least he wasn't sure about it and so ***that's why he literally asked about it***. I'm not at all sure this constitutes in mere *different wording* of the same question.

Further, the fact that the unexpected output is the reason these questions exist doesn't map one to one with the *problem* each OP had. **Or is it really the case both OPs are just asking why they get garbage output?** Looking at the text quoted above, it seems to me that the mention of *garbage* is only understood in composition with the other sentences in the question **being about in-memory structure.**

**From the comments:** At no point it is claimed that dupes need to be an ***exact*** match. Here, for example, I'm particularly bothered by the fact that the answer on the newer post would seem pretty perplexing, at least the opening part, if read as an answer to the older post. Far from asking for an an exact match, but at least should be read coherent. I will be in the wrong of course, in case most people think the new answer could go smoothly enough when coupled with the old question. Let me know in an answer or comment if you feel like it, but please try explain how this is or isn't the case.

Am I missing anything here? please correct me.

Comment: [Voting on meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Votes are often used to express (dis)agreement with the general premise of the Meta question. These votes won't affect your main site reputation.

Comment: @Cerbrus Didn'r realized about how voting works here in regards to expressing agreement. Thanks!

Comment: Most any experienced C++ programmer understands this problem.  So the exact text of the question is not that important.  The only role it plays is as a source of keywords for the Google search indexer so programmers can find this Q+A back in the future.  Sometimes it is useful to leave very clumsy wording and misspellings in place, on the assumption that a Google searcher will get that wrong as well.  Not that often.  If you think you can do this better then just make your own edit.  But keep in mind that it has been edited many times before, hard to improve.

Comment: @HansPassant Every C++ programmer has his/hers problems. He had a problem of understanding this has nothing to do with "memory allocations". And his other problem, leading him to the former one, was not knowing how to printout what he wanted to. I agree with you 100% that the exact text is not the problem, but I think you'll agree this is still the case (what were the OP's problems), regardless of what you put in this edited title text. Again, what is there to prevent other people from reaching the same conclusions like this OP originally had?

Comment: _"Or is really the case both OPs are just asking why they get garbage output?"_ ___YES___ That's what I've been saying the whole time. The _reason_ both questions exist is because both OPs _ran into the same problem:_ They're not getting the output they expected. Both cases of unexpected output were cause by the same problem, and can be solved with the same solution. That's ___plenty___ to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Considering the votes on this question and answer, maybe it's time for you to stop repeating what you're saying, stop doubting what we're saying, and just accept that this is how duplicate closures work.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know you where you stand friend. Just left unsatisfied with the reasoning, and being that there isn't an official stand regarding dupe closure I think it should be OK for me to keep trying to get to the bottom of this. There's nothing personal here, I'm not *doubting* what you're saying, it just leads me to another question. And I got encouraged to keep at it as some upvoting did finally arrive. So far as you can see I remain with the question regarding whether this *reason behind the post* and *the problem the OP had* are really the same thing. and that's completely OK to disagree.

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess it's also OK for us to have different reading of the same question text, each reading leading us to a different perception of what exact *problem* the OP had. I guess it would have been easier if he was a part of this discussion. In case he did have he problem I'm thinking he had, he perhaps could have written it better.

Comment: You realized that can _only_ be answered when both of the involved OPs answer here, right? For dupes, this is close enough. Dupes don't need to be an ___exact___ match.

Comment: I meant both OPs of course, yes. Further, at no point it is claimed that dupes need to be an ***exact*** match. Here, for example, I'm particularly bothered by the fact that the well received answer on the newer post, would seem pretty perplexing, at least the opening part, if read as an answer to the older post. Not being an exact match, but at least should be coherent. I guess I feel it's not an open and shut case as your'e portraing it to be. I could be wrong of course.

Comment: How many edits do you think this question needs? After a while it may be better to just let it go.

Comment: @yivi Perhaps I'm missing something here, as a newbie in here. Is editing my post activates some kind of trigger so for example you and the other user writing the answer here are notified and so is makes my edit seems like new post or repeating the post or something like that? I wasn't aware of such as I do not get such notifications for any post being edited... Please teach me if this is the case, as it might explain behavior I'm getting here such as "*maybe it's time for you to stop repeating what you're saying*"...

Comment: As in main, edited questions get bumped to the top of the "active" question list.

Comment: @yivi Oh! Well that makes me feel a bit awkward right now... Apologies are in order then, at least to you here friend. wow. Wait by main you mean main site of SO?? The same thing you describe applies there as well?

Comment: Yup, it applies to the main site as well. It's a mechanism to give more visibility to edited questions. In the main site is easy to get lost in the crowd, since there are so much more traffic, but the low intensity of meta makes your edits to become much more noticeable.

Comment: @yivi I think the last few times were mostly format fixing and typos! I should really take this into consideration and read carefully before submitting. Extremely sorry and of course no more editing for this. Feel very silly right now : (

Comment: @yivi I forgot to personally thanks you -- I believe you have performed a great service for me here on the site by explaining this to me. This has been constructive. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 11):

Your answer is solving the ***exact same problem*** as the dupe is. The OP of the newer question just worded the *same* question differently.

Both questions resulted from the OPs getting unexpected output. That unexpected output is the core reason these questions exist.

They're properly marked as duplicates. I've also reverted the title back again, as looking at the question, they're asking why they get garbage output. He isn't asking how memory is allocated. He's asking how to properly output the char pointer.

Furthermore, your rollback edit reverted some improvements to the question.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Care to let me know how the issue at hand fares with you though? Is directly asking about a different issue (memory vs. printing in this case), given the same symptom caused both OPs to ask their question, is enough to constitute a duplicate? I feel like thanks to Cerberus's answer I have now refined my wonderment to this specific query. In case you don't answer I will assume zero statements, excluding perhaps you're just busy! : )

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I generally believe that yes, two different questions that are answered in a similar manner are to be duplicated in one way or the other (meaning, choosing one of the questions to be the target, and the other to be the duplicate). In this case, this is *well* over my head, though I think your answer is more detailed, in the sense that it teaches me more than the linked duplicate, so maybe the older question could me marked as duplicate of the newer one, but I really can't vote for either way knowledgingly.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier See, this a problem I think, as if you reverse the order of duplication here as you suggest then my answer appears to talk about something completely different: The older question is directly about how to print, while the newer one, originally addresses memory allocations, hence the answer opens with: "*The "memory locations" are contiguous in the exact ...*" -- which would seem quite unclear to a reader as to how it relates to the older question, had he/she is to be reading it as an answer to their question about printing. I think, maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @Cerberus I think I'm starting to see more and more examples of such closures. See [this from just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453773/a-question-about-c-bit-operation-overflow) for example -- The new OP clearly thought `-O2` g++ flag is the underlying cause for his unexpected result, but the mechanism in reality causing the wonderment was the same as for an older question (UB when shifting too far). If this is somewhat of an unwritten law for dupes, could you perhaps add such concise emphasis to your answer? I think it would be perfect that way.

Comment: ... I see no reason to update my answer.

Comment: Ok, as the only person answering could you at least let me know here in a comment if I got this unwritten rule correctly? This rule seems like a logical prerequisite to what's written in your answer, that's the only reason I'm asking.